# Can the accept button be moved a little further away from the downvote button on mobile?

Tags: feature-request, design, mobile-web

On my mobile device's browser I almost always accidentally hit downvote when I meant to hit accept. Then I have to zoom the page to a ridiculous size to un-downvote and accept the answer. Could the button be moved a little further down to help prevent the issue and save a little time?